# Calculate capacitance value and voltage rating in the event of ESD pulses

Tags: capacitor, capacitance, esd, discharge

I have a input power filter circuit.

It has ESD protection capacitors which help to protect the downstream circuit from ESD pulses.

[image: ESD Capacitor]

**ESD Capacitors Specifications :**

C0001, C0002, C0003, C0004 = 47nF, 100V, 10%, 0805

**My ESD Pulse Specifications :**

- Contact discharge : +/-4kV & 150pF / 330Ohms
- Contact discharge : +/-8kV & 150pF / 330Ohms
- Air discharge : +/-15kV & 150pF / 330Ohms

Can someone please help me on how to do the calculations so as to justify that my capacitance value and voltage ratings of the capacitors are within the limits designed?

**My understanding :**

For example, I take the +/-4kV & 330pF spec

Q=CV ;

4kV * 150pF = 600nC

This charge will then get to the input ESD capacitors :

V=Q/C;

600nC / 47nF = 12.76V (And in this step, should I consider the capacitance value for the single cap 47nF or should I consider the equivalent series capacitance value of 23.5nF?)

So, my voltage rating of the capacitor 100V > 12.76V is appropriate for this pulse.

Is my approach correct?

My questions :

1. The above calculation I have done for only positive 4kV. Can someone help me on how to understand when negative 4kV is applied and how to go about the calculation?
2. I have justified only for the capacitance voltage rating. How to justify for the capacitance value? Can someone help me with the formula to justify the capacitance value?

Comment: I would certainly use a simulation tool for this (as I would for your later question on inrush current).

Comment: Yes I would use a simulation tool too. But I would just want to understand / calculate it theoretically before

Comment: Why are you placing these 47N caps in series? You should place them all parallel.

Comment: With respect to **what** do you apply the ESD pulse?

Comment: With respect to ground

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 4 kV pulse from 150 pF in series with 330 ohms

The charge is 0.6 uC (as you said) and, ignoring the 330 ohm resistor (which limits the peak current), that charge becomes (after applying the pulse) distributed between the 150 pF and 2 series 47 nF capacitors. Given that the 150 pF is really small compared to 23.5 nF (the series capacitance of two 47 nF caps), you can assume (without much error) that the charge is all "adopted" by the 23.5 nF.

This means that the voltage will be 25.53 volts. In other words twice the value you calculated because you need to regard the two 47 nF caps as being in series.

But, this doesn't accommodate the series diode and two more capacitors of 47 nF. In effect, the calculation above is valid for -4 kV. For +4 kV the capacitance is just 47 nF (ignoring the volt drop on the diode) because 2 series capacitors of 47 nF in parallel with an identical series connection of 2x 47 nF = 47 nF.

So, with a positive 4 kV pulse the voltage is 12.77 volts and, for -4 kV it is 25.53 volts.

> *Is my approach correct?*

Broadly speaking yes. And, more importantly, it is conservative in that we have assumed a worst case of the 330 ohm resistor being shorted and the diode (D0002) being shorted.

Rating the capacitors at 25 volts or above would be OK for this example.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But 2 questions. 1. At -4kV, the diode blocks and only the first set of capacitors get impacted. So, 25.53V get accumulated. But the bottom capacitor is connected to ground right. So, my understand is that, the 25.53V will equally split into 12.76V across each cap, with the bottom side being +ve with respect to the top side. So, the charge will immediately get a path to ground through the bottom resistor. Am I correct? And my second question, could you please help me to check value of the capacitance whether the chosen is appropriate? Please help me with that formula.

Comment: *Bottom resistor*??? *What formula*???

Comment: Sorry, What I meant by Bottom resistor  (It was actually bottom capacitor, Let me edit that) - "How is the voltage accumulated in each capacitor when -4kV is applied (I mean the polarity of the voltage across each capacitor after the pulse is applied) and how will that 25.53V get discharged to the ground? And the second question is, similar to the steps above to validate the voltage rating of the capacitor, is there a way / formula / calculation to validate my selected capacitance value?

Comment: The polarity of each capacitor follows the polarity of the applied voltage. The -25.53 volts will remain -25.53 volts until something discharges it. It can't be discharged through the diode so, unless you have a bleed resistor it remains. The formula is the one you (and I used) and that is that charge is (always) conserved.

Comment: Yes. So, the bottom part of the capacitor is connected to the ground terminal and it is positive when compared to the top part of the capacitor. In PCB, the ground terminal will be spread across the board. So, due to some plane resistance, won't the charge bleed out and the capacitor get discharged (considering the board is not powered). Is my understanding correct? And supposed, if the circuit is already powered and I apply this ESD pulse, the negative voltage will be accumulated across the capacitor and the positive voltage will be connected to the ground. So, what happens here?

Comment: And please check whether my validation of capacitance value correct? Q(initial) = 4kV * 150pF =600nC. C(Final) = 600nC / 4kV = 150pF. So, I need a capacitance of 150pF minimum. But I have 47nF, which is higher than 150pF. Is my calculation & understanding correct?

Comment: I really can't make any sense of your last comment. I don't understand what you are trying to determine. That formula is Q = CV or C = Q/V and they are both the same. Plane resistance will not discharge the capacitor. Parallel resistance will.

Comment: I strongly urge you to use a simulator to work out practicalities of variations you might come up with.

Comment: Sure, I will. The thing that I was trying to pass across in my last comment is to validate the required capacitance value for the ESD suppose. For the 4kV pulse, the Charge Q = 150pF * 4kV = 0.6uC. So, this 0.6uC is the final charge that will be applied. So, to check what should the maximum capacitance be inorder to withstand this pulse, I tried to use the Energy conservation formula as you said. So, Final capacitance, C(final) = 0.6 / 4kV = 150pF. So, I need to have a minimum capacitance of 150pF, inorder to withstand this ESD pulse. Is my calculation correct?

Comment: No, I said **charge conservation**; energy is NOT conserved. There is no final capacitance other than what you have in your diagram and that is a bunch of 47 nF capacitors - they share the 0.6 uC charge with the 150 pF capacitor when a connection is made.

Comment: @Newbie I think the equation you want depends on how high the voltage in the circuit is allowed to become. The ESD provides a charge of 0.6uC. If the max allowed voltage is Vmax, then the required capacitance is C = Q/Vmax. So, if you want to limit Vmax to 25V, you need a capacitance of 0.6uC-25V = 24 nF.

Comment: Yes thank you Huisman. But in my recent question, I just wanted to figure how high the voltage in my circuit can be. Could you help with that?

Comment: When a positive 4kV pulse is applied, Does the 12.77V is shared by each capacitor? So each capacitor will hold 3.1925V? And what is the maximum voltage can the capacitors withstand in the case of positive pulse?? Is it 4 x 100V = 400V ? Or only 2 x 100V = 200V (since the 2 sets of series capacitors are in parallel). 100V is the voltage rating of the capacitor.

Comment: The 12.77 volts will appear where you have an arrow called "ESD pulse". If you ignore the small forward volt drop of the diode you can say that there is 6.38 volts across C0002 and C0004 and 6.38 volts across C0001 and C0003. If the rating is 100 volts then the capacitors can withstand 100 volts on each meaning 200 volts at the point marked "ESD pulse". This assumes the capacitors are perfectly matched. If they are mismatched by 10% i.e. one is 51.7 nF and the lower one is 42.7 nF then there will be proportionately more voltage developed across the capacitor with lower capacitance.

Comment: Could you also please guide me on how to do the ESD Capacitor calculation when the 330Ohm Series Resistor is not ignored

Comment: @Newbie - the 330 ohm resistor is irrelevant to charge transfer - the same amount of charge gets transferred whatever the value. 50% of the energy is lost in the process whatever the resistor value. The only difference that the 330 ohm makes is limiting the peak current and elongating the time that the charge is transferred. If you need this information you should use a simulation tool (after all, if I were doing it then that's what I'd use). If you need a theoretical answer, may I suggest you raise a new question.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Let me raise a new question